# Match strings across all columns in dataframe and impute or replace values

Tags: r, string, if-statement, lapply, zoo

**Problem**

I have a dataframe, `df`, with 82 columns, where after the fourth column, the remaining columns contain the same beginning string in triplicate. E.g. `mass.mean, mass.stdev, mass.rsd, density.mean, density.stdev, density.rsd` etc. I need to:

1) Match the triplicate columns with partial strings (e.g. `mass` or `density`) and

2) Replace those matched column's values with specific computations if conditions are met (e.g. if columns in `df` contain the string `mass` then replace NA's with the previous value (impute) `zoo::na.locf` or if columns in `df` contain the string `density` then replace NA's with zero.

To me it seems like I would need to incorporate `grepl` `lapply` and an `ifelse` ladder, but I can't seem to pull it together. If I can avoid converting from wide to long that would be best as my dataframe contains > 450k rows.

**Example Dataframe**

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame("A" = sample(0:100,8), 
             "B" = sample(0:100,8),
             "C" = sample(0:100,8), 
             "D" = sample(0:100,8),
             "mass.mean" = c(1, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA, 2, 1), 
             "mass.stdev" = c(1, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 2, 1),
             "mass.rsd" = c(0, NA, 0.1, 0.1, NA, NA, 0.2, 0.1), 
             "denisty.mean" = c(6, 5, 7, NA, NA, NA, 6, 4), 
             "denisty.stdev" = c(3, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 2, 1),
             "denisty.rsd" = c(0.8,0.2, 2, NA, NA, NA, 0.5, 0.7),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

print(df)

   A  B  C  D mass.mean mass.stdev mass.rsd denisty.mean denisty.stdev denisty.rsd
1 29 55 24 66         1          1      0.0            6             3         0.8
2 78 45  4 70        NA         NA       NA            5             1         0.2
3 40 94 32 53         2          1      0.1            7             1         2.0
4 86 44 93 58         3          1      0.1           NA            NA          NA
5 91 65 86 28        NA         NA       NA           NA            NA          NA
6  4 54 66 14        NA         NA       NA           NA            NA          NA
7 50  9 60 91         2          2      0.2            6             2         0.5
8 83 84 97 84         1          1      0.1            4             1         0.7
```

**Desired Output**

```
   A  B  C  D mass.mean mass.stdev mass.rsd denisty.mean denisty.stdev denisty.rsd
1 29 55 24 66         1          1      0.0            6             3         0.8
2 78 45  4 70         1          1      0.0            5             1         0.2
3 40 94 32 53         2          1      0.1            7             1         2.0
4 86 44 93 58         3          1      0.1            0             0         0.0
5 91 65 86 28         3          1      0.1            0             0         0.0
6  4 54 66 14         3          1      0.1            0             0         0.0
7 50  9 60 91         2          2      0.2            6             2         0.5
8 83 84 97 84         1          1      0.1            4             1         0.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `is.mass` to identify the `mass` columns and then run `na.locf` on those. (The second `na.locf` line performs a backwards fill in case there are leading NAs.  You can omit that line if you know that there are none or if you want to preserve leading NAs.)  Similarly define `is.density` to indicate the density columns and then use `na.fill` on those.  An alternative to the two `na.locf` lines is the single line `df[is.mass] <- na.approx(df[is.mass], method = "constant", rule = 2)`

```
library(zoo)

df.orig <- df # optional in case you want to keep the input around

is.mass <- grepl("mass", names(df))
df[is.mass] <- na.locf(df[is.mass], na.rm = FALSE)
df[is.mass] <- na.locf(df[is.mass], na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE)

is.density <- grepl("density", names(df))
df[is.density] <- na.fill(df[is.density], 0)
```

giving:

```
> df

   A  B  C  D mass.mean mass.stdev mass.rsd density.mean density.stdev density.rsd
1 29 55 24 66         1          1      0.0            6             3         0.8
2 78 45  4 70         1          1      0.0            5             1         0.2
3 40 94 32 53         2          1      0.1            7             1         2.0
4 86 44 93 58         3          1      0.1            0             0         0.0
5 91 65 86 28         3          1      0.1            0             0         0.0
6  4 54 66 14         3          1      0.1            0             0         0.0
7 50  9 60 91         2          2      0.2            6             2         0.5
8 83 84 97 84         1          1      0.1            4             1         0.7
```

### Note

We used this as the input.  This is the same as in the question except we corrected the spelling error in density.  Also we eliminated                  `stringsAsFactors` since the data is entirely numeric.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame("A" = sample(0:100,8), 
             "B" = sample(0:100,8),
             "C" = sample(0:100,8), 
             "D" = sample(0:100,8),
             "mass.mean" = c(1, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA, 2, 1), 
             "mass.stdev" = c(1, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 2, 1),
             "mass.rsd" = c(0, NA, 0.1, 0.1, NA, NA, 0.2, 0.1), 
             "density.mean" = c(6, 5, 7, NA, NA, NA, 6, 4), 
             "density.stdev" = c(3, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 2, 1),
             "density.rsd" = c(0.8,0.2, 2, NA, NA, NA, 0.5, 0.7))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should solve your 'density' columns issue:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with("density")),function(x) {if_else(is.na(x),0,x)})
```

The 'mass' one is a little trickier as you have to get the previous values, and it looks like you want to impute from the last time there was a non-NA value. this solution handles the case where the first row contains an NA by keeping the NA as i'm not sure what you want to happen then.

```
imputePrev <- function(x) {
    l <- seq_along(x) # declare vector of appropriate length rather than growing
    for (i in seq_along(x)){
        if (i == 1){
            l[i] <- x[i] # always keep the first row
            next
        } else if (is.na(x[i])){
            for (j in 1:(i-1)) { # get the last non-NA value if one is available
                if (!is.na(x[i-j])){
                    l[i] <- x[i-j]
                    break
                }
            }
        } else {
            l[i] <- x[i]
        }
    }
    return(l)
}

df %>%  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("mass")),imputePrev)
```

Comment: When I ran `imputePrev` it filled columns, that started with NA's, with integers (1:). I know it's getting tough, but if I could back impute from the nearest value, up, that would be ideal. E.g. `c(NA,NA,NA,3,4,5,NA,6)` would be `c(3,3,3,3,4,5,5,6)`